# How to calculate anomaly using awk

Tags: awk

A have a file:

```
file.txt
1       32
2       34
3       32
4       43
5       25
6       34
7       65
8       34
9       23
10      44
```

I would like to find anomaly on send column:

my below script printing anomalies considering row-2 to row-10 values. It is not considering row-1 values.

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{
                f=1;
                if($1 >= 1 && $1 <= 10){
                                                count++;
                                                SUM+=$2;
                                            };
                next
            }
     FNR==1 && f==1{
                AVG=SUM/count;
                next
                   }
     ($1 >= 1 && $1 <= 10){
                print $1, $2-AVG
            }
    ' file.txt file.txt
```

My desire output:

```
1       -4.6
2       -2.6
3       -4.6
4       6.4
5       -11.6
6       -2.6
7       28.4
8       -2.6
9       -13.6
10      7.4
```

I got a solution of it:

```
awk '{f=$1>=1 && $1<=10}f && NR==FNR{sum+=$2; c++; next}f{ print $1, $2-(sum/c) }' file.txt file.txt
```

I am still wondering why the first script is not giving correct answer.

Comment: What do you mean with anomaly? Do you mean the deviation from the mean value?

Comment: Yes. It is deviation from mean value. Thank you.

Comment: The first script is not giving the correct value, because you skip the first line in the second pass of your file `(FNR==1 && f==1) { AVG=sum/count; next }`. Because of the next statement, you skip the computation of the deviation from the mean value for the first record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first script in the OP is not giving the correct value, because you skip the first line in the second pass of your file. This is seen in the statement `(FNR==1 && f==1) { AVG=sum/count; next }`. Due to the `next` statement, you skip the computation of the deviation from the mean value for the first record.

This is an efficient computation of the deviation from the mean in a double pass:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){s+=$2;c++;next}
     (FNR==1){s/=c}
     {print $1,$2-s}' file file
```

If `file` contains values bigger than 10 or smaller than 1 in the first, column, but you only want to see this for values in the range of `[0,10]`, then you can do:

```
awk '($1<1 || $1>10) {next}
     (NR==FNR){s+=$2;c++;next}
     (FNR==1){s/=c}
     {print $1,$2-s}' file file
```

There are still other optimizations that can be done, but these only become beneficial when working with extremely large files (many millions of lines).

Comment: Yes, file contains 100 rows (it is actually years) and I was looking for the 1st 10-years anomaly. Thanks for making it clear...

Answer (score 4):

Since this is just 2 columns file, this can be done in a single pass `awk` also:

```sh
awk '{map[$1] = $2; s += $2}
END {mean = s/NR; for (i in map) print i, map[i] - mean}' file

1 -4.6
2 -2.6
3 -4.6
4 6.4
5 -11.6
6 -2.6
7 28.4
8 -2.6
9 -13.6
10 7.4
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems here: (a) there is an issue when multiple lines have the same value in the first column. (b) the for loop does not traverse the indices in the same order as you add them (c) I know you know all this ;-)